# Jmeter is not running the ssh sampler when it run by hudson and it the run the ssh sampler when it is run manually

Tags: jmeter, hudson

I am currently working on the function automation of APIs using the jmeter. I have run a nightly build by using the hudson. In my automation scripts i have added some "ssh command" sampler to capture some traces.
When i run the jmeter script from my local machine it runs the "ssh command" sampler but when i trigger it from the hudson it do not run any "ssh command" sampler. ia m not able to recognize the problem.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made reference to a local machine and "the hudson", which makes me suspect these are different machines? Try logging onto the Hudson box and doing your SSH from there. That will tell you if there is something blocking ssh between those nodes.

If that doesn't show you the problem, you can see what is going on a little better by running `jmeter` in `client-server`. Open the jmeter server on you Hudson box, connect to it with the client and you will see when you get to the SSH login that it is unable to login.

This could be because there is something blocking ssh connections from your Hudson box or because there is some permissions error (which may not be presenting itself on your local machine since you are already logged in).

The jmeter should stop. In the command prompt window where you started the server, if permissions are the problem, you will see (where user.name is the account you are trying to ssh in as):

> Kerberos username [user.name]:
>
> Kerberos password for user.name:

Comment: Thanks. It works. Jmeter does not fail because it does not able to login on the local machine from hudson box. That the major confusion for me.